# php shell_exec & permissions

Tags: php, permissions

I have the following directories:

```
/var/www/temp
/var/www/users (S3 mount)
```

the user which the following php is run on is `www-data`:

```
mkdir("temp/id247439757");
addSomeFilesInTheAboveDirectory();
shell_exec("temp/id247439757 users/id247439757");
```

the problem is that it's not moving the directory from temp/ to users/! All the files stay in the temp directory.

I think the user that executes shell_exec is www-data as well! how can I fix this? Please note that this problem *cannot* be addressed to the fact that it's a mounted directory as, if I directory do mkdir("users/id247439757") it *does* work.

Comment: ? maybe you forgot to specify an actual command to be executed? like 'mv' ?

Comment: ...... i'm dumb. 2 characters are just so small to see.

Comment: LOL, I expected that to be a typo in the stripped down example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the "mv" command inside the shell_exec call:

```
shell_exec("mv temp/id247439757 users/id247439757");
```